# Angular 9 card body with scrolling content?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am using an Angular card that is using flex layout to set the card header and card footer at the top and bottom of the available vertical space.

In the card body I am displaying an accordion component that when the accordion panels are expanded the required display can extend beyond the default card body vertical space.

Currently, when I expand the accordion panels the card footer is pushed vertically off the bottom of the browser window. What I want is to keep the card footer in place, and have the content in the card body scroll within the fixed vertical size card body.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show this in codepen? Also please post the markup that you have tried.

Comment: Could you provide an angular stackblitz with this problem?

Comment: share your code so we can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try this css with your own deserved max-height.

```
 ::ng-deep .card{
  max-height: 100px !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Adding...

```
style="height: 0px; overflow-y: auto"
```

... the card body tag fixes this